# jQuery UI Dialog opens only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I found answer to this questions on SO but it seems that the problem is different here. I cannot open it again after it has been closed.

EDIT: Ok, seems that there are errors in my Jquery code elsewhere.

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });
  $('#opener').click(openDialog);

})

var openDialog = function(){


   $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'buttons',{
      "Cancel":function(){
         $('#dialog').dialog('close');
      }
  });


 $('#dialog').dialog('open');

};
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The     dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Open twice?

Comment: NO after I close it I would like to be able to open it again.

Comment: are there any javascript errors?

Comment: I have tried the same code and is working fine for me

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/DSNt5/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try to add destroy method call on dialog close:

```
var openDialog = function(){
   $('#dialog').dialog('option',
    close: function () { $(this).dialog("destroy"); },
    'buttons',{
      "Cancel":function(){
         $('#dialog').dialog('close');
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EA2Dg/1/) as it works

edits: updated link as it wasn't the one

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `hide` instead of `close` in

```
$('#dialog').dialog('option', 'buttons',{
  "Cancel":function(){
     // notice the hide here
     $('#dialog').dialog('hide');
  }
});
```

i haven't tested it but, as far as i can remember it. 
hope this helps